# Using processing and getting an unexpected token on my array. #hackathon

Tags: debugging, processing

```java
String[] files= {};

int[] fileNumber = {0};
String commandPromptTxt = "";
    String CPTDummy = "";
String blankDummy = "";
String[] currentFile = {};
void makeFile(String[] file, int fileNum, String name1, int level1, int[]parents1, int[] children1, String type1) {
  //Warning if you make a file and use the same file number more than once you will override the file

  files[fileNum]= {"10"};
};
```

So I have that amazing piece of code in processing and I am getting an error `unexpected token:{` where I say `files[fileNum] = {};` also even when I enter values into the brackets I get the same error. Any ideas of a fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clean up that code a little so that we can actually read it? (remember, you're asking fellow human beings to read your code). And you'll probably find out what's wrong simply by cleaning it up. If not, we'll be better able to help.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I cleaned it up. Sorry about the mess before

Comment: Some things to think about: `String[] files= {};` is equivalent to `String[] files = String[0]`. Do you really want that? Probably not. Similarly, `int[] fileNumber = {0};` is an `int[1]` with as only content the value 0. Again, is that really what you want? Because the code after that suggests you don't. Your method call also has way too much in its signature, and what it does has odd names. There is no reason for all those `1` in the parameter names. Finally, `files[fileNum]= {"10"};` can never work. You can't use `{...}` for assignment, only to initialise as part of a declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you including brackets at all?

The syntax you're using is an **array initializer**. You use it correctly here:

```java
String[] files= {};
```

This initializes your `files` variable to an empty array. You also use the syntax correctly here:

```java
int[] fileNumber = {0};
```

This initializes your `fileNumber` variable to an array with a single index, and in that index is the value `0`.

This line is where it stops making sense:

```java
files[fileNum]= {"10"}
```

First of all, you've already initialized your `files` variable to an array **with zero indexes**. That means that even if this would compile, you'd get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because you're trying to use indexes of an array that doesn't have any.

Secondly, you're misusing the array initialization syntax. I'm pretty sure you don't want the indexes of your array to **also be arrays**, otherwise you'd have to make them 2D arrays.

So, to sum it up, you need to do two things:

**1:** Initialize your arrays to actually have indexes. Something like this:

```java
String[] files = new String[10]; //array with 10 indexes
```

**2:** Stop misusing the array initialization syntax and just pass values into the array indexes:

```java
files[fileNum]= "10";
```

You might be better off using `ArraysLists` instead though. Then you don't need to know how many indexes you'll have ahead of time, and you can simply call the `add()` function to add stuff to them.

More info can be found in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been ignoring this bug and writing other functions and this will help me a lot.

Comment: I actually do need 2D arrays but will go and do more research.

Comment: I fixed my own problem by using your suggestions and just adding the second dimension like so  String[][] files= new String[10][5]; Thank you once more